# CPLEX (12.5) Java API, solve a LP as an IP

Tags: java, integer, cplex

Is there a simple way to solve an LP model as an IP, i.e. convert the continuous variables to integral once without any other changes to the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Java / Concert API, you can change a variable or variable array from continuous to integer by adding an [IloConversion](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.cplex.help%2Frefjavacplex%2Fhtml%2Filog%2Fconcert%2FIloConversion.html) object to your model.  If you have an IloNumVar or IloNumVarArray x, that you want to make integer you can create the conversion object with

```
// create the conversion object and save a reference
IloConversion makeInteger cplex.conversion(x, IloNumVarType.Int);

// To modify the model, add the conversion object to the model
cplex.add(makeXInteger);

// solve the model, 
IloBool success = cplex.solve();

// revert the model back to continuous
cplex.remove(makeXInteger);
```